# Add column index of min value for each row in new column

Tags: r

I have an existing df in which I would like to add a new column with the column index of the minimum value of a specific column range - in this case [,28:30].

I was already able to add two columns to get the mean and sd of this range, however, when I'm using which.min to fill my last column, it doesn't work.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
df$m1 <- apply(df[,28:30], 1, mean)
df$sd <-apply(df[,28:30], 1, sd)
df$indxcol <- apply(df[,28:30],1, which.min)
```

The code above works but it adds the name of the column and the index value whereas I just want the index as integer.

I've also tried this with mutate but it's not adding anything

```
df$m1 <- apply(df[,28:30], 1, mean)
df$sd <-apply(df[,28:30], 1, sd)
df%>%mutate(indxcol = apply(.[,28:30],1, which.min))
```

here is a sample of my df

```
df <- structure(list(YY = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), DD = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4), MM = c("Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug"
), Date = structure(c(13729, 13729, 13729, 13729, 13729, 13729
), class = "Date"), `ID (FIFA)` = c("FRA D1", "FRA D1", "FRA D1", 
"FRA D1", "FRA D1", "FRA D1"), Country = c("France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France"), League = c("Ligue 1", 
"Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1"), Season = c("2007/2008", 
"2007/2008", "2007/2008", "2007/2008", "2007/2008", "2007/2008"
), HOME = c("Bordeaux", "Caen", "Lille", "Monaco", "Paris SG", 
"Rennes"), AWAY = c("Lens", "Nice", "Lorient", "St Etienne", 
"Sochaux", "Nancy"), `Final Scores` = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), ...12 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 2), ...13 = c("H", "H", "D", "D", "D", "A"), ...14 = c("U", 
"U", "U", "U", "U", "U"), `ET/Pen/Awd` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `1st Half Scores` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), ...17 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...18 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), ...19 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2nd Half Scores` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...21 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...22 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), ...23 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), FTMoneyline...24 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...25 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...26 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Payout, %...27` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FTMoneyline...28 = c(2.2, 
    2.4, 1.72, 1.9, 1.72, 1.72), ...29 = c(2.75, 2.75, 3, 2.9, 
    3, 3.2), ...30 = c(3.4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4.5), `Payout, %...31` = c(89.9038461538462, 
    89.795918367347, 89.7079276773296, 89.1946580331849, 89.7079276773296, 
    89.596295760382), `FT TG 2.5...32` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...33 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `FT TG 2.5...34` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...35 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), OUTCOME = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 3), REFGAME = c("G423", "G424", "G425", "G426", 
    "G427", "G428"), m1 = c(2.78333333333333, 2.71666666666667, 
    3.24, 2.93333333333333, 3.24, 3.14)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the df output I get with my first code

```
df <-structure(list(YY = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), DD = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4), MM = c("Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug"
), Date = structure(c(13729, 13729, 13729, 13729, 13729, 13729
), class = "Date"), `ID (FIFA)` = c("FRA D1", "FRA D1", "FRA D1", 
"FRA D1", "FRA D1", "FRA D1"), Country = c("France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France"), League = c("Ligue 1", 
"Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1"), Season = c("2007/2008", 
"2007/2008", "2007/2008", "2007/2008", "2007/2008", "2007/2008"
), HOME = c("Bordeaux", "Caen", "Lille", "Monaco", "Paris SG", 
"Rennes"), AWAY = c("Lens", "Nice", "Lorient", "St Etienne", 
"Sochaux", "Nancy"), `Final Scores` = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), ...12 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 2), ...13 = c("H", "H", "D", "D", "D", "A"), ...14 = c("U", 
"U", "U", "U", "U", "U"), `ET/Pen/Awd` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `1st Half Scores` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), ...17 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...18 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), ...19 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2nd Half Scores` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...21 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...22 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), ...23 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), FTMoneyline...24 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...25 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...26 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Payout, %...27` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FTMoneyline...28 = c(2.2, 
    2.4, 1.72, 1.9, 1.72, 1.72), ...29 = c(2.75, 2.75, 3, 2.9, 
    3, 3.2), ...30 = c(3.4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4.5), `Payout, %...31` = c(89.9038461538462, 
    89.795918367347, 89.7079276773296, 89.1946580331849, 89.7079276773296, 
    89.596295760382), `FT TG 2.5...32` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...33 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `FT TG 2.5...34` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...35 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), OUTCOME = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 3), REFGAME = c("G423", "G424", "G425", "G426", 
    "G427", "G428"), m1 = c(2.78333333333333, 2.71666666666667, 
    3.24, 2.93333333333333, 3.24, 3.14), sd = c(0.600694043031337, 
    0.301385688667085, 1.65311826558175, 1.05039675043925, 1.65311826558175, 
    1.39097088395121), indxcol = list(c(FTMoneyline...28 = 1L), 
        c(FTMoneyline...28 = 1L), c(FTMoneyline...28 = 1L), c(FTMoneyline...28 = 1L), 
        c(FTMoneyline...28 = 1L), c(FTMoneyline...28 = 1L))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to assign back to the  original object  `df <- df%>%mutate(indxcol = apply(.[,7:9],1, which.min))`.  Columns 7 and 8 are `character` class.  You may need to convert to numeric before doing that.  `str(df[7:9])`

Comment: A faster option is `max.col` `df <-  df %>% mutate(across(7:9, as.numeric)) %>% mutate(indxcol = max.col(-1 * .[7:9], 'first'))`

Comment: thanks  a lot for your answer @akrun. It's working great for this df, but actually I'm trying this on another dataframe, and the results include the name of the column as well and I don't understand why. Here is a

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of a small example that shows the issue. Your first set of codes seems to have typo `apply(l[,7:9],1, unlist(which.min))` i.e `unlist` is used

Comment: Sorry @akrun, my mistake, i've modified the dataframe in my question, and actually i'm trying to get the column index of the min value in col [,28:30]. and using your first answer, it includes the names of the column and the value whereas I would like to have only the integer value

Comment: I get `df %>% mutate(indxcol = max.col(-1 * .[28:30], 'first')) %>% .$indxcol#
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Comment: Your code output is `df%>%mutate(indxcol = apply(.[,28:30],1, which.min)) %>% pull(indxcol)#
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Comment: May be you are confused with the format of the tibble output.  It prints only a minimum number of columns and collapse the others.  If you want to check the output. use `View` or check `str(df)` after `df <- df%>%mutate(indxcol = apply(.[,28:30],1, which.min))`

Comment: Yes indeed your code works. However I'm using this in a for loop to do this for several df, and the output in the new column is different and adds the name of the col as well. Let me re edit my post to clarify things. thanks again

Comment: Can you show your for loop

Comment: for(i in 1:nrow(eurteam)){
  df<-get(eurteam[[i,1]])
    df$m1 <- apply(l[,28:30], 1, mean)
    df$sd <-apply(l[,28:30], 1, sd)
    df <- df%>%  mutate(indxcol = apply(.[,28:30],1, which.min))
}

Comment: Based on what you showed.  `df` is created fresh in each loop and it gets updated.  I guess you may need a `list` i.e. `lst1 <- vector('list', nrow(eurteam))` and within the loop, `lst1[[i]] <- eurteam[[i, 1]]; lst1[[i]]$m1 <- apply(l[, 28:30], 1, mean)` not clear what is `l` here

Comment: sorry I forgot to modify, l is df actually. I will work with your answers and see If i'm able to make it work. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221649/discussion-between-m-o-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the peculiar output could be that in some row/rows, there are only `NAs` for the subset of columns, resulting in `integer(0)`

```
which.min(c(NA, NA, NA))
#integer(0)
```

With a example

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, NA), col2 = c(2, 3, NA), col3 = c(3, 4, NA))
```

Now, the output is a `list`

```
apply(df1, 1, which.min)
#[[1]]
#col1 
#   1 

#[[2]]
#col1 
#   1 

#[[3]]
#integer(0)
```

Instead of `which.min`, we can wrap with index 1 to coerce the `integer(0)` to `NA`

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) which.min(x[!is.na(x)])[1])
#[1]  1  1 NA
```

---

In the OP's code, it would be

```
df$indxcol <- apply(df[,28:30],1, function(x) which.min(x[!is.na(x)])[1])
```

Comment: That was the problem indeed, with your solution it's working just fine, thank you for your help @akrun

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and acknowledging @akrun for all the work locating the `NA` issue.  Using **OP**'s data but adding a row of NA values to test.  Printing only the columns of interest with a `select` statement.  We'll test the results of `which.min` and if it is anything other than `length == 1` declare it NA

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- add_row(df, .after = 6)

df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(m1 = mean(c_across(28:30)),
          sd = sd(c_across(28:30)),
          idxcol = ifelse(length(which.min(c_across(28:30))) == 1, 
                          which.min(c_across(28:30)), 
                          NA)
          ) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(28:30, 38:40)

#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#>   FTMoneyline...28 ...29 ...30    m1     sd idxcol
#>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>
#> 1             2.2   2.75   3.4  2.78  0.601      1
#> 2             2.4   2.75   3    2.72  0.301      1
#> 3             1.72  3      5    3.24  1.65       1
#> 4             1.9   2.9    4    2.93  1.05       1
#> 5             1.72  3      5    3.24  1.65       1
#> 6             1.72  3.2    4.5  3.14  1.39       1
#> 7            NA    NA     NA   NA    NA         NA
```